# Android Studio 1.3.1 windows7 emulator x64 download

Tags: android-studio, 64-bit, emulation

I have Android Studio 1.3.1 on windows 7 x64.   I notice all the emulators are running on x86.  I can not get the emulator to run.  Can someone help me solve this problem or help me find a download, x64 emulator for Android Studio 1.3.1 on windows 7 x64?

I am new to the app game. So please dumb down your answers!  Great community thanks all for your help!